# How to get the default listener from a view in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I want to modify my `ExpandableListView` so that on normal click it expands the clicked-on group and collapses all others and on long click it only expands the clicked-on group. This would be very trivial if there was `getOnClickListener()`:

```
OnClickListener oldListener = view.getOnClickListener(); // DOESN"T EXIST
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        collapseAll();
        oldListener.onClick(v);
    }
}
view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        oldListener.onClick(v);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But there's no such method. I could do it via `ExpandableListView.expandGroup(int position)`, but I'd need to find the position from the view, which makes it more complicated that it should be. Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the view position in the view itself by setting its position to its tag..

```
view.setTag(position);
```

You have to do this while adding the child views, probably in the adapter class..

Then  when you need the position get it from the view itself by calling `view.getTag();`

Comment: Not bad, but I'm already using the tag. I could store there both, but again, this isn't a nice solution.

Comment: It works, but it's far from perfect. I want to *exactly what it did before.* And it looks like it's dependent on the API level --- now it's `expandGroup(position, true)` which didn't exist before 14.